# Resize Android ToggleButton dynamically?

Tags: android, togglebutton

How do I dynamically resize a ToggleButton?

/Henrik

Answer (score 0):

how about

ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton(context);

`button.setWidth(int pixels);`
and 
`button.setHeight(int pixels);`